# How to iterate for loop with limiting sequence in fish shell

Tags: for-loop, fish

I want to limit sequence in for loop. All my tries were unsecsessfull. What Am I doing wrong?

I thought that this should work:

```
for x in ((seq 100)[50..55])
  echo $x
end
```

Comment: You can try this, `for x in {50..55};do echo $x ; done`.

Comment: An alternative with a `while` loop and without `seq`: `set i 50; set end 55; while [ $i -le $end ]; echo $i; set i (math $i + 1); end`

Answer (score 59, accepted):

With fish:

```
for i in (seq 50 55); echo "$i"; end
```

Output:

```
50
51
52
53
54
55
```

Comment: thanks. Did you find it in fish shell documentation?

Comment: You won't find it there because `seq` is not a fish thing - it's an external tool (see `type seq`). On GNU/Linux systems it's a part of GNU coreutils.

Answer (score 5):

You have one too many pairs of parenthesis. In fish parenthesis do what `$(command)` and `` `command` `` do in bash or zsh. So just do

```
for x in (seq 100)[50..55]
    echo $x
end
```

And, of course, for this specific example you don't even need the slice notation since you can just tell the seq command to begin and end with the desired values.